# SQL Server : output inserted.Id join with inserted temporary user defined table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got a problem.. I use a stored procedure with user defined table (`@logs`). I insert it to other database table (`InOutLog`), with command `OUTPUT into`, where I get `inserted` id.

The main problem is what I want to insert my user defined table to 2 database tables:

1. `InOutLog`, where I get inserted id and..
2. Want to take inserted id and other defined table values (`l.Title+';'+l.Comment`) and insert it to table `MessageLog`

But I can't access `l.Title+';'+l.Comment`. Also I can not find any simple solution to merge my user defined table and temporary table with inserted id values..

Here is the code:

```
insert into InOutLog(NFCId, UserID, DateEnter, DateLeave, ProjectId, 
Status, ServerDateEnter)
output inserted.Id, inserted.DateLeave, l.Title+';'+l.Comment, inserted.UserId 
into MessageLog(TagLogId, MessageDate, Answer, UserId)
  select l.NFCTagId, l.UserId, l.ScanDate, l.StartDate, @projectID, 0, getdate()
  from @logs l
```

Any suggestions? What's the best practise in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use MERGE not INSERT.

This allows you to access the source tables in the OUTPUT clause for INSERTions.

Example: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/01/06/merge-and-output-the-swiss-army-knife-of-t-sql.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts (i.e. the code example) here.